# How should I keep webpages consistent

Tags: php, html, css

I'm fairly new to web-centric design and programming.

I've got a HTML + CSS with PHP page I'm quite happy with. It's got a header, a main content area, and a sidebar.
Now I'm working on my second page. The second page should have the same look as the first page. I'll reuse the CSS, but there seems to be a lot of repetition between the first and second pages (the content in the header, and the sidebar, for example, is almost identical).

Is it normal to repeat things over multiple pages? If, later, I want to change something, I'm going to have to change it in (potentially) numerous places; that seems rather silly, so I presume I'm missing something.

I thought perhaps I'd use the "small parts" from my CSS in a "larger" wrapper, encompassing the entire Header, perhaps, and then include that in both pages; I'm not sure if that's the right direction I should be heading (or how I'd do it).

I also thought perhaps I could use PHP to dynamically generate the page each time, wrap the generation in a class, and then end up with something like `myClass->generateHeader()`. I'm using PHP to generate some of the page anyway, so the conceptional leap isn't too great; on the other hand, I imagine that generating the page each request is worse in terms of performance, and (from my brief searching) seems to involve several hundred lines of PHP to generate a rather short stretch of HTML, (assuming it's anything more complicated than a bunch of `echo` statements containing the HTML I'd have written anyway.

Searching for "creating HTML templates" is rather fruitless, but I'm not sure what kind of keywords I'd be using to ask how this is normally handled.

How do you adhere to DRY and avoid repeating yourself over several related pages in a website?

Comment: this kind of discussion probably belongs in programmers stack exchange

Comment: I dynamically generate my html with php for simplicity.  I have a php include file that I include in most of the pages of my site so that I can use the methods there to generate the html I want and it allows me a lot of variety.  I set the parameters of my methods to allow for extreme changes to content with very little text on the page.

Comment: Can the downvoter please provide feedback on the question? It might be better suited to programmers.SE but it's still a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php include method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php in order to not have to repeat parts of your page that are always needed. For example, the header and footer, navigation, etc..

To answer your other question, using a class to store html sections is another way to go and can prove to be useful. It also won't add a lot of extra processing time unless your class needs to do a lot of calculations upon initialization.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to seperate out a header and footer file and include them.  A good book on this would be Larry Ullman's [php and mysql for dynamic web pages](http://www.larryullman.com/books/php-and-mysql-for-dynamic-web-sites-visual-quickpro-guide/).

But for a quick overview go to: http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2009/08/php-header-and-footer-templates/

Answer (score 0):

If you fear that some things do repeat across multiple resources, keep them out.

Add them in post-processing instead.

You do this best on the server level. You can also add caching if needed at that level, so your page only get's generated once and no-more again (or until the cache expires).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt K, that is probably more programmers stack exchange related but I'll provide some tips anyway.

I think the normal thing is to create some kind of header/footer files. For example, your header file would include everything you want on every page, i.e. logo, menu, css includes etc. And the footer is useful for: closing wrapper divs, google adsense code etc.

Once these files have been created, for each page you just do:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>

BODY OF PAGE

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

If any of the components are static components (e.g. the sidebar), then you can put the static HTML in a file and simply `include` it in the relevant place. (OO alternative: have a View object pull in the static HTML for you.)

If you need some custom logic in these components, then an `include` could still work, but since you discuss a class-based alternative I'd suggest building an [MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) into your application.

An MVC framework would probably consider the header/sidebar/footer etc. as *partial views* (smaller components in the main view), or part of your overall *layout* (your header/sidebar/footer wrap around your main content body).

The layout option makes a lot of sense as it decouples the view for the main content from your overall idea of how the page components stick together. It also means it's really easy to modify the layout (for instance, put the sidebar on the right instead of the left by changing one layout file).